# Program closes right after last line of code ruby

Tags: ruby

When I try to put in a code such as:

```
    print "Enter A Value: "

first_num = gets.to_i

print "Enter Another Value: "

second_num = gets.to_i

puts first_num.to_s + " + " + second_num.to_s + " = " + (first_num + second_num).to_s

print "Was That Correct? "

MyValue = gets.to_s

puts MyValue + "This is what you typed. Correct?"
```

after the last puts command, the program closes directly after. Is there any way to stop that from happening? I want the program to stay open until the person closes it manually. Not including loops or hitting enter.

Comment: I am just a beginner at ruby, so I would highly appreciate if you can edit the code directly.

Comment: Why would you want it to not close when the program is finished

Comment: I want the program to actually show the last puts command before it closes, and If there is a way to make it stay open until the user closes the program, that is what I want, or you could say looking for

Comment: You can add one more `gets` at the end

Comment: like @Wand Maker said, just add another gets at the end and it will wait for <Enter>.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with how you open the program. You are probably on some GUI and the command line opens when you start the ruby application. You won't have that problem if you start the application from the command line

Comment: Are you using a Windows command prompt, which exits after you run the ruby script? There are other better ways to operate command line programs than double-clicking them. http://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution

Comment: Assuming you are doing something like double-clicking, the more appropriate way to work with a command line program would be to open the command prompt, `cd` to the directory of your file and run it as `ruby yourfile.rb`

Comment: @RandomChannel I think you're confusing the program with the CUI. The ruby program you posted does not come with a command line. It's on the OSes to pick which utility to use. If you want full control over the window, you can use a GUI toolkit (like [shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) )and output the results there.

Comment: please stop making this even more negative, I have my answer. I can't delete it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add another `gets` to leave the window open, but the real problem isn't really to do with the Ruby language, but with how you run the program.

If just you want the program to *not quit*, you could just add

```
loop { sleep 10 }
```

At the end of your program, which is not a great idea but sounds like what you want.

If you're on Windows,

1. Open cmd or powershell
2. Run the ruby program from the command line

=>Window doesn't close after running the program.

This is the right way to run command line programs.

Answer (score 2):

you could make a `while` loop... run the program continuously until they respond "yes" to correct.

Also note that variables that start with capital letters are constants, so `myValue` is preferred over `MyValue` in this case.

```
correct = nil
while correct != 'yes'
  print "Enter A Value: "
  first_num = gets.to_i
  print "Enter Another Value: "
  second_num = gets.to_i
  puts first_num.to_s + " + " + second_num.to_s + " = " + (first_num + second_num).to_s
  print "Was That Correct? "
  myValue = gets.to_s
  puts myValue + "This is what you typed. Correct?"
  correct = gets.chomp.downcase
end
```